# how to iterate over multiple html paragraphs in jinja

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I want to iterate over a database containing

1. a title
2. a paragraph

How do I split the content over 2 columns?

looking to make this code:

```
{% for stor in story %}
 <h1>{{stor.title}}</h1>
  <p class = "story">{{stor.body}}</p> 
  {% endfor %}
```

look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <h1>header text</h1>
      <p>paragraph text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <h1>header text</h1>
      <p>paragraph text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

while displaying text from a database

Comment: Have you tried out `<table>` ?

Comment: Did you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTML Tables` for showing the data in columns. You can do like this:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Story</th>
  </tr>
  {% for stor in story %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{stor.title}}</td>
      <td>{{stor.body}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

For more detail on `HTML Tables` : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp